# No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, react-native-ios

I am using react native and iOS hybrid development environment and I initialized a few Umeng sdk in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, which is using `launchOptions` as a parameter. Below is what my code currently looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 ........
 [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate=self;
 [UMessage registerForRemoteNotificationsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions Entity:entity 
 completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted) {
    }else{
    }
 }];
 ........
```

Now I want to pull that part of code out and make it a separate function which is like:

```
- (void):(UIApplication *)initSDK:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 ........
 [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate=self;
 [UMessage registerForRemoteNotificationsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions Entity:entity 
 completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted) {
    }else{
    }
 }];
 ........
```

and call this initSdk() method in another class, like in SDKModule.m:

```
[[AppDelegate sharedAppDel] initSdk];
```

I googled a few solutions and did follow stuff in my AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m is like:

```
...
 + (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDel
 {
   static AppDelegate *theAppDel;
     @synchronized(self) {
         if (!theAppDel)
             theAppDel = [[self alloc] init];
     }
     return theAppDel;
 }
...
```

But I am getting `No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'initSdk'`. Can someone please help me with this? I am a RN developer mainly and dont have much experience with objective-c.

Comment: Add that definition also to the header file and be sure to include the header in the calling .m file.

Comment: It's the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813577/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-was-thrown-while-invoking-xxx-on-target You need to read how to declare methods in Objective-C and how to call them... See my comment on your other question.