# Unrecognized selector sent to instance was thrown while invoking xxx on target

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native-ios, appdelegate

I declared a new method in AppDelegate.m, like:

```
-(void):(UIApplication *)aMethod :(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
......
    [UMessage registerForRemoteNotificationsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions Entity:entity 
     completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
        }else{
        }
    }];
......
}
```

in my AppDelegate.h:

```
- (void)aMethod;
```

in my anotherClass.m:

```
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [appDelegate aMethod];
```

And when I run the code in anotherClass.m I got the error. Does anyone know where I am wrong?

Comment: The function you have declared accepts a dictionary and returns a pointer to `UIApplication`. The function you are calling is being passed no parameters. The error says that a method called `aMethod` That accepts no parameters was not found

Comment: Copy paste the full error message. The selector should help. But as said, `[appDelegate aMethod]` would be ok if you declared: `-(void)aMethod{...}`. Oh, and in Objective-C, don't use `:` in method with nothing before, it's a verbose language, so in fact `-(void):(UIApplication *)aMethod :(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is totally unclear... It might be `-(void)aMethodWithApplication: (UIApplication *)application andLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and then `[appDelegate aMethodWithApplication: [UIApplication sharedApplication] andLaunchOptions: ???]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the signatures of the methods in .h and .m don't match and for external classes the .h file is relevant.

But there is a more significant mistake/misunderstanding. Actually you are extending `UIApplicationDelegate` which makes no sense. Methods which pass a specific instance as first parameter are only useful when being called in the instance where the `delegate` is declared in, in your case in `UIApplication`.

The signature of a method declared in `AppDelegate` but called from an arbitrary class should be the same as a normal method

.h

```
-(void)aMethod:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

.m

```
-(void)aMethod:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    ...
    [UMessage registerForRemoteNotificationsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions 
                                                       Entity:entity 
                                            completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
        }else{
        }
    }];
...
}
```

and use it

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSDictionary  *options = ...
[appDelegate aMethod: options];
```